# Regex to avoid spaces AND a dot followed by hyphen or hyphen followed by a dot

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need a regex for an input pattern that doesn't allow spaces and a "." followed by a "-"

i.e.:

this-is-valid.com

this is not valid

this.-is-also-not-valid

this-.is-also-not-valid

Comment: aahhhhh...homework questionss...love them (not true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key will be defining the group of characters that are allowed on the left and right sides and just adding `"-"` to the right-hand-side. I've just used `\w` here:

```
\b((?:\w|-)+\.\w+)(?:[^-]|$)
```

[[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/uN1eP4/2)]

Comment: You almost got it!, the problem I'm having is that "valid.input.-comments" this is a valid when it shouldn't

Comment: @user2882664 You'll note that the capture will take "valid.input" in that case. If you want to allow multiple `"."`s then you'll need to decide where `"-"` characters should be allowed relative to the `"."` characters. For example is this valid: "valid-.input-.comments"

Comment: @user2882664 Please edit your question to specify what you are actually asking. I've given you a regex that solves all the requirements set forth by the original question.